# datetimepicker set min date for one datepicker based on another datepicker

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I have two datetimepicker `#FromDate` and `#ToDate`, I want to set `#ToDate`'s min value to `#FromDate`'s selected value

I have used below code but not working.

```
$('.datepicker').datetimepicker({
    format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
    ignoreReadonly: true,
    defaultDate: new Date(),
    maxDate: new Date(),
    useCurrent: false

});

$('#FromDate').on('dp.change', function () {


    $('#ToDate').datetimepicker('destroy');
    $('#ToDate').datetimepicker({
        format: 'DD/MM/YYYY',
        ignoreReadonly: true,
        defaultDate: $('#FromDate').val()

    });

});
```

Comment: Please share your HTML and/or give a fiddle/snippet that shows your issue. Which datetimepicker are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#FromDate').on('dp.change', function (e) {
    $('#ToDate').data("DateTimePicker").minDate(e.date);
});
```

is the first datetimepicker your `$('#FromDate')`? since you have it set as `$('.datepicker').datetimepicker({`

Comment: @JijuJohn give a look at this jsfiddle its updating the minDate https://jsfiddle.net/jb2eqtyw/1/

Comment: thanks, its was not working because I have used the code $('#ToDate').data("DateTimePicker").('destroy');

Answer (score 0):

can you try destroying the datepicker

```
$('#ToDate').data("DateTimePicker").('destroy');
```